# .htaccess to pass FULL URL into other PHP link as $_GET

Tags: .htaccess

From `.htacces` file, how to pass/redirect the FULL URL to another URL as GET Variable?

Like:

```
http://www.test.com/foo/bar.asp
```

will be redirected to:

```
http://www.newsite.com/?url=http://www.test.com/foo/bar.asp
```

With **Full Url with Domain**.
I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.asp http://www.newsite.com/?url=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But it is going out like:

```
http://www.newsite.com/?url=?%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: I suggested this: RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.asp http://www.newsite.com/?url=$1\.asp [NC,L] but I just realized that wouldnt capture the domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.asp http://www.newsite.com/?url=$1.asp
```

Comment: But it is only returning: `?url=foo/bar.asp` What i need is FULL URL like `?url=http://www.test.com/foo/bar.asp`

Answer (score -1):

If the initial domain and protocol is always the same then you can use

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.asp http://www.newsite.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F$1\.asp
```